# Is there something like a TStringList from Delphi in the Java (Android) language?

Tags: java, delphi

I am starting to **develop in Android** and decided to have a go at the native **java language**.

When starting to use new languages, I tend to create a library of code creating routines with the same name which perform the same function as in the libraries I already have.

F.i. in my Classic Asp library I have a IntToStr() ... function which is an equivalent of the IntToStr() of Delphi, although I know that VBScript does not need such a function - it makes my code in the different languages much more readable and thus make it easier to switch between languages.

Coming from a **Delphi background**, I have a lot of library code in Delphi which uses **TStringList** classes.

**Is there anything equivalent in Java** ? Or how would you solve this ?

Comment: `TStringList` is so versatile that it's rare anyone needs *all* its capabilities at once. It can associate objects with each of its string entries. It can be sorted using custom comparison functions. It can manage "name=value" strings. It can silently ignore duplicate entries, or raise an exception. It can insert and remove entries at arbitrary positions. It can keep itself sorted, or it can maintain the original insertion order. If you tell which of those features you need to use, you're more likely to get suggestions of Java classes that will most closely meet your needs.

Comment: @Rob Kenndy: name=value pairs in original or sorted order, deleting, replacing and inserting values must be possible. I also subclassed TSTringList to store an integer in the Object property - it's amazing how many times you need to count something , or store something which can be represented by an integer, associating this with a string value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need:

**org.apache.commons.collections.map.ListOrderedMap**

Answer (score 4):

A delphi StringList looks to my like a list of key/value pairs. Java has structures for collections of key/value pairs (`Map`), but the implementation `TreeMap` and `HashMap` do not keep the insertion order of the keys. A good start for a custum Java datatype could be:

```
public class TStringList {  // unconventional Java name, but you like to keep the delphi names
  private class Entry {
    String key;
    Object value;  // to keep it flexible
  }
  private List<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<Entry>();

  // add some constructors

  // implement methods of delphis StringList
}
```

(Note: the stub does not implement a JCA interface (like `List`) because the class is intended to mimic a delphi type and not to act as a collection)

Answer (score 2):

Is it a simple List of Strings? If yes, use generics instead:

```
LinkedList<String> myStrings = new LinkedList<String>();
myStrings.add("hello");
String s = myStrings.get(0);
```

Comment: It's actually just an array of strings with some nice helper routines.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there's a *exact* replacement for TStringList, because it is very flexible and does not correspond to one exact data structure class on java Containers - actually most TStringList's functionality have to be done using some other classes. 
Two years ago I implemented in Java a TStringList object. There's capable classes in java that can help you. I don't know if I still have that source, was only an experiment.